What tree am I?
I can't be planted in any soils.
My attempt to produce oxygen always foils.
I grow and bear fruits. But they can't be boiled.
My branches sometimes get coiled.
This is an original puzzle.

You are a

Family Tree!


I can't be planted in any soils.

A family tree is not a literal tree...

My attempt to produce oxygen always foils.

...and hence cannot produce oxygen.

I grow and bear fruits. But they can't be boiled.

Family trees grow via marriage and the children are the fruits who (hopefully!) don't get boiled

My branches sometimes get coiled.

Family trees can get extremely complicated over many generations, and for instance with many royal family trees there may be some inbreeding causing branches to 'coil'


Excellent answer!
